# TypeScript type that only accepts keys of an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't know if this is really possible, but I have an existing object that maps string keys to React components.

I want to create a type to essentially make a parent component only accept keys of the icon mapping object as a prop:

```
export const icons: { readonly [key: string]: React.VFC } = Object.freeze({})

type IconProps = {
  name: // every key of `icons`
}

export const Icon: React.VFC = ({ name }) => {
  return icons[name]({})
}
```

Again, I don't know if this even is possible, but it'd be super awesome if it was.

Also, if you have suggestion for a different title to make it more searchable and descriptive of what I'm actually trying to accomplish, I'd love to update it.

Comment: Wait, what's the purpose of `Object.freeze({})` here?  You have ensured that `icons` has no properties at all.  Assuming you don't want `type IconProps = {name: never}` I think it would useful if you could modify the code so as to constitute a [mcve] .Good luck.

Comment: The general idea is to use `keyof`. But agree with @jcalz that we need a minimal example in order to help.

Comment: sorry that the example was unclear. `icons` would be the object that’d map a string key to a react component. for example `const icons = Object.freeze({ Add: () => /* svg /* })`. the object is frozen such that it’s immutable to consumers

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to create an `enum`(IconName) to see the names of the icons and assign this to the key.

```js
type IconName = 'homeIcon' | 'ballIcon';
type IconMap = {
    [key in IconName]?: React.VFC;
};


const icons: IconMap = {
  homeIcon: <ExampleComponent />,
  ballIcon: <ExampleComponent />
};
```

To see this type on the parent component you need to put the `IconName` type into the component [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-types), like this:

```js
type IconProps = {
  name: IconName
}

export const Icon: React.VFC<IconProps> = ({ name }) => {
  // on this return you need to return only the value.  
  return icons[name]; 
}
```

Comment: feels bad. i was hoping i could do it without duplicating key names