# Only accept keys of a given object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a TypeScript class that is initialized with an object and has a method which can only take keys of that object as arguments. So:

```
class MyClass {
  properties = {};

  constructor(properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }

  // Passed propNames should only be keys of this.properties
  pick(...propNames) {
    return propNames.reduce((obj, name) => ({ 
      ...obj, 
      [name]: this.properties[name]
    }), {});
  }
}
```

This seems similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819951/typescript-type-that-only-accepts-keys-of-an-object), but I can't figure out how to apply it in this case, since the properties are passed in from the outside.

```
const props = { key: 'value', key2: 'value2' };
interface PropKeys {
  key: string;
  key2: string;
}
type KeyName = keyof(PropKeys);

// But what do I do to the class to get this to work?
const instance = new MyClass(props);
instance.pick('key', 'key2'); // Great
instance.pick('key3'); // Should throw a type error
```

Is this possible? Is there a way to do it without explicitly defining the `InstanceKeys`, but instead deriving them from the props passed while initializing the instance?

I'm trying to wrap my head around generics, and was thinking maybe something like this:

```
class MyClass {
  properties = {};

  constructor<Type>(properties: Type) {
    this.properties = properties;
    type TypeKeys = keyof(Type);
  }
  
  pick(...propNames: TypeKeys[]) {
    return propNames.reduce((obj, name) => ({ 
      ...obj, 
      [name]: this.properties[name]
    }), {});
  }
}
```

But this raises two type errors:

- On the `<Type>`: "Type parameters cannot appear on a constructor declaration."
- On the `TypeKeys[]`: "Cannot find name 'TypeKeys'." (I mean, makes sense; it's out of scope.)

---

**UPDATE**: This feels closer, but I'm running into an issue where the properties are first defined on the class (above the constructor):

```
class MyClass<PropType extends Properties> {
  properties: PropType = {};

  constructor(properties: PropType) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }

  pick(...propNames: Array<keyof(PropType)>) {
    return propNames.reduce((obj, name) => ({ 
      ...obj, 
      [name]: this.properties[name]
    }), {});
  }
}
```

The TS error I'm running into on that line is

`Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'PropType'. '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'PropType', but 'PropType' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Properties'`

The issue here is that any `properties` passed in may have their own keys, but must be instances of type Properties, which constrains the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generic type needs to go on the `class` declaration, not on its constructor. Then `keyof Type` needs to be an anonymous type. You also need to type `properties` so TypeScript knows it can be indexed with `keyof Type`, which I've done in this example by giving it a type of `Partial<Type>`.

I've also used a type assertion so that the initial `{}` object of your `reduce` is typed as `Partial<Type>`, so TypeScript will understand how to index it after it's been created.

```
class MyClass<Type> {
  properties: Partial<Type> = {};

  constructor(properties: Type) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }
  
  pick(...propNames: (keyof Type)[]) {
    return propNames.reduce((obj, name) => ({ 
      ...obj, 
      [name]: this.properties[name]
    }), {} as Partial<Type>);
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVeAHApgPmgG8BYAKGmiwCcB7XKgFwEscIAuaABTEabBAzZ80ALxEAvgG4yZCsBoA7CAyoBXYAxpUAFNTo5erDplwBKIrIrQGACyYQAdHvrNWoyrRcsI08tHGWllhMwADW2g6RzgByYAC2RtDaoTjwNABm0CY4pgDaALrmJH4UVDgMqlQKHnSxCY5lACbqONraNABGAFYANNAK8TmiBNqE0JZW0JEOnb3jJVa5Awn5HLb2Tp4GrhBLg-kT-qZ9hOLQkFw8zPyCuHimvhQBpM9AA)